# Expandable child listview item click on image

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, expandablelistview

[image]

In the  image above , I want to increase the textview(red) value by 1 when plus button is pressed and  decrease by 1 when minus is pressed in child listview item . I don't want to click the whole list item but only plus and minus imageviews. What is happening now, I have to double click on the list item to increase or decrease the value of textView (red) . Also when i scroll the listview, the values on listitems automatically disappears . How to resolve these 2 issues . please help ??

listitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
         android:text="tv_name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
         />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_price"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
               android:text="tv_price"
        android:textColor="#000000"
         />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_desp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
                         android:layout_weight="1"

                     android:text="tv_desp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
         />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_minus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/minus" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_items"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
                     android:text="0"
                     android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
         />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_plus"
    android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="5dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/plus" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_subheaders.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_items_wo_sub_headers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="tv_sub_headers"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

SubheadersFragment .java

```
   public class SubheadersFragment extends Fragment {
        private int mResourceId;
         TextView tv_sub_headers;
         String sub_headers_string;
         String  sub_header,item;
         ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
        ExpandableListView expListView;
        List<String> listDataHeader;
        TextView tv_no_items,childPosition;
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
        String[] items;
        int no_of_items;

         public static SubheadersFragment newInstance(int resourceId,String tv_sub_headers ) {
             SubheadersFragment widgetFragment = new SubheadersFragment();
                widgetFragment.mResourceId = resourceId;
                widgetFragment.sub_headers_string=tv_sub_headers;

                return widgetFragment;
            }

         @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                                     ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                return inflater.inflate(mResourceId, container, false);
            }
         @Override
            public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
             tv_sub_headers= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_sub_headers);
                expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvExpSH);

             tv_sub_headers.setText(sub_headers_string);
             try {
                JSONArray jArraySub_headers=new JSONArray(sub_headers_string);
                listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
                listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

                   items=new String[jArraySub_headers.length()];

                for (int i = 0; i <jArraySub_headers.length(); i++) {//headers

                    JSONObject c = jArraySub_headers.getJSONObject(i);

                     sub_header = c.getString("sub_header"); 
                     item = c.getString("items"); 
                     items[i]=item;

                     listDataHeader.add(c.getString("sub_header"));

                }

                ///for (int j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {

                    JSONArray jArrayItemsVeg=new JSONArray(items[0]);
                    List<String> vegListString = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int j = 0; j <jArrayItemsVeg.length(); j++) {//headers
                        JSONObject c = jArrayItemsVeg.getJSONObject(j);

                     //   vegListString.add(c.getString("name")+"*"+c.getString("price")+"*"+c.getString("description"));
    //                 

                        if(c.has("item_types"))
                         vegListString.add(c.getString("name")+"*"+c.getString("price")+"*"+c.getString("description")+"*"+c.getString("item_types"));


                        else 
                          vegListString.add(c.getString("name")+"*"+c.getString("price")+"*"+c.getString("description"));

    //                   
    //      
                    }

                    JSONArray jArrayItemsNONVeg=new JSONArray(items[1]);
                    List<String> NonvegListString = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int j = 0; j <jArrayItemsNONVeg.length(); j++) {//headers
                        JSONObject c = jArrayItemsNONVeg.getJSONObject(j);
                      //  NonvegListString.add(c.getString("name"));
                 //       if(c.has("description"))
                        if(c.has("item_types"))
                            NonvegListString.add(c.getString("name")+"*"+c.getString("price")+"*"+c.getString("description")+"*"+c.getString("item_types"));

                        else 
                                                NonvegListString.add(c.getString("name")+"*"+c.getString("price")+"*"+c.getString("description"));

        //      
                        //                      else 
    //                          NonvegListString.add(c.getString("name")+"*"+c.getString("price"));

                    }
                    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), vegListString); // Header, Child data
                    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), NonvegListString);
            //  }
                listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

                expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        ImageView iv_plus= (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.iv_plus);
                        ImageView iv_minus= (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.iv_minus);
                         tv_no_items= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_items);

                        iv_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                no_of_items=Integer.parseInt(tv_no_items.getText().toString())+1;
                                tv_no_items.setText(no_of_items+"");

                            }
                        }); 

                        iv_minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                if(no_of_items>0){

                                no_of_items=Integer.parseInt(tv_no_items.getText().toString())-1;
                                tv_no_items.setText(no_of_items+"");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        String header=listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
                        String items=listDataChild.get(
                                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition);
                        String[] itemsArray=items.split(Pattern.quote("*"));
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getActivity()
                                ,
                                itemsArray[itemsArray.length-1]
                                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        return false;
                    }
                });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
         private void prepareListData() {
                listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();

                // Adding child data
    //          listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
    //          listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
    //          listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

                // Adding child data
                List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
                top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
                top250.add("The Godfather");
                top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
                top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
                top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
                top250.add("The Dark Knight");
                top250.add("12 Angry Men");

                List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
                nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
                nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
                nowShowing.add("Turbo");
                nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
                nowShowing.add("Red 2");
                nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

                List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
                comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
                comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
                comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
                comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
                comingSoon.add("Europa Report");


            }
    }
```

ExpandableListAdapter.java

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    int no_of_items;
    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
    TextView     tv_no_items;
    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
         String[] itemsArray=childText.split(Pattern.quote("*"));
    //  if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        //}


        TextView tv_name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_name.setText(itemsArray[0]);

        TextView tv_price = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
        tv_price.setText("\u20B9 "+itemsArray[1]);

        TextView tv_desp = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_desp);
        String fontPath = "fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf";
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(_context.getAssets(), fontPath);  
        tv_name.setTypeface(tf);
        tv_price.setTypeface(tf);
        tv_desp.setTypeface(tf);

        //Toast.makeText(_context, Arrays.toString(itemsArray), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(itemsArray.length>=3){
            ;
            if(itemsArray[2].contains("{") && itemsArray[2].indexOf("{")>4 ){
                tv_desp.setText("");


            }

            else
            tv_desp.setText(itemsArray[2]);


        }
        else
            tv_desp.setText("");

//      ImageView iv_plus= (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_plus);
//      ImageView iv_minus= (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_minus);
//           tv_no_items= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_items);
//        iv_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              no_of_items=Integer.parseInt(tv_no_items.getText().toString())+1;
//              tv_no_items.setText(no_of_items+"");
//              
//          }
//      }); 
//      
//        iv_minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//          
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              if(no_of_items>0){
//
//              no_of_items=Integer.parseInt(tv_no_items.getText().toString())-1;
//              tv_no_items.setText(no_of_items+"");
//              }
//          }
//      });
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What happened when you used the code that is commented out in the adapter? That is the way I would have done it.

Comment: SubheadersFragment .java       expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener()

Comment: ya i tried that code in adapter but whole item is clicked first .. only then plus minus button are enabled

Comment: Perhaps you can look into using the ViewHolder pattern, it might help the handling of the clicks better.

Comment: @Androidiseverythingforme this is recycling problem with listview you have to use viewholder for better performance and for your problem you have to maintain state of view because it might change after scroll so you can search for maintaining listview state for scrolling so you can get better idea